# PowerPivot Calculate filters wont work

Tags: sql, excel, powerpivot

I have the following tables

Orders:

```
OrderID|Cost|Quarter|User
-------------------------
   1   | 10 |   1   | 1
   2   | 15 |   1   | 2
   3   |  3 |   2   | 1
   4   |  5 |   3   | 3
   5   |  8 |   4   | 2
   6   |  9 |   2   | 3
   7   |  6 |   3   | 3
```

Goals:

```
UserID|Name |Goal|Quarter|Sum
-----------------------------
   1  |John | 20 |   1   | x
   1  |John | 15 |   2   | x
   2  |Bob  | 12 |   2   | x
   2  |Bob  | 15 |   3   | x
   3  |Homer|  5 |   3   | x
   3  |Homer|  7 |   4   | x
```

Now what I want to do is in the second table sum up all orders that have the UserID from the current row and are in the current rows quarter.

My first attempt was:

> =CALCULATE(sum(Orders[Cost]);Orders[Quarter]=[Quarter];Orders[User]=[UserID])

The result should be:

```
UserID|Name |Goal|Quarter|Sum
-----------------------------
   1  |John | 20 |   1   | 10
   1  |John | 15 |   2   |  3
   2  |Bob  | 12 |   2   | 15
   2  |Bob  | 15 |   3   |  8
   3  |Homer|  5 |   3   | 11
   3  |Homer|  7 |   4   |  0
```

But here I get the error: `Column "User ID" cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.`

To try something out, I used fixed values:

> =CALCULATE(sum(Orders[Cost]);Orders[Quarter]=2;Orders[User]=1)

Which resulted not in an error message but not fully working either. I now get

```
UserID|...|Sum
   1  |...| 3
   1  |...| 3
   2  |...| 
   2  |...| 
   3  |...| 
   3  |...| 
FYI: the empty space in SUM is really empty.
```

The crazy thing is if I do the following:

> =CALCULATE(sum(Orders[Cost]);Orders[Quarter]=2;Orders[User]=Orders[User])

I get:

```
UserID|...|Sum
   1  |...|  3
   1  |...|  3
   2  |...| 
   2  |...| 
   3  |...| 11
   3  |...| 11
```

Which is almost what I want. But I dont understand, why some cells are working.

Is there any way to make this work as I want to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Urganot**,

The desired output is quite simple if you take advantage of all features available in PowerPivot - mainly the ability to create [relationships between datatables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413437(v=sql.110).aspx).

I have copied you data and there is was one thing missing - a table of *Users*. You can get one from your database/IT department, or simple [create it in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-list-in-excel-HA001034626.aspx) from the data you already have available. Just make sure it doesn't contain any duplicates, otherwise you won't be able to define the relationships.

Datatables I am using in my next steps look like this (*User* table is on the right):

[image]

Add all the table to Powerpivot data-model (PowerPivot ribbon -> Add to Data Model), switch to *diagram view* and [connect *Orders* and *Goals* tables to *User* table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-relationships-in-diagram-view-in-power-pivot-HA102922010.aspx) (simply drag UserID from tables Orders and Goals onto Users table). It should look like this:

[image]

Once this is done, it's very easy to get the numbers you want. Just define two new *Calculated Fields* (Powerpivot ribbon -> Calculated Fields -> *New Calculated Field*). Make sure you pick the target table for *Users* and enter this formula:

For Sum of Order Value

```
=SUM(Orders[Cost])
```

For Sum or Target Goals

```
=SUM(Goals[Goal])
```

In Excel 2013, the interface looks like this.

[image]

In order to see numbers by quarter, you would need to have a table with unique quarter numbers as well - simply follow the steps for creating *Users* table. Again, link in *Diagram view* to other tables and you should end up with this:

[image]

Using Quarter table as a [slicer](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/slicers.html) makes it probably the best way how to analyze/filter the numbers:

[image]

So that's the answer: **relationships in PowerPivot**.

It could be very difficult to do it otherwise, not to mention slow once you start dealing with thousands of rows. I believe this approach is much better compared to "the old way" (nested LOOKUPs & IFs).

Also, keep in mind that the data you use is not structured in the best way - especially quarters are not distinguished by year etc.

Anyway, I hope this helps - if there is anything unclear, just let me know in the comment section. Or simply go ahead and download [my source Excel file (2013 version)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ulr60f1l8jna01/Relationships.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This works perfectly.
Could someone answer another question?

If I want to multiply the results with a value of another table (none on those 3). Should I do this as a calculated field, as a row in a table or in excel?

Comment: What would be the value to match the rows?

Comment: I would match the rows using the UserID. Imagine the Goal value would be in another table. how can I calculate the sum/goal?

Comment: I would simply link the table to Users table, create a new calculated field and it should work just fine.

Comment: Great. it works. Thanks.

After calculating some other values, I ran into another problem.
I want to divide each goal row by the sum of all goals. this doesnt work because in each row there is only the goal of the User not the sum of everyone. Also is there a way to tell powerpivot to ignore the filters from excel for specific columns?

Comment: Urganot, would you please ask a new question - comment section is not the best tool for this :)

Comment: Here's the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354487/powerpivot-using-a-calculated-value-in-another-calculation